# Excel VBA Macro to Set alignment left if a cell contains a string in ANY worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I can get this to work on one worksheet, but not for ALL worksheets. I want to find any cell containing the word "Figure" in the cell string and set the alignment of that cell to left justified. What am I doing wrong here?

'If any cell in the worksheet contains the word FIGURE align it to left

```
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

Set SrchRng = Range("$A1:$AZ200")

For Each WS In Worksheets
     With WS

        For Each cel In SrchRng
            If InStr(1, cel.Value, "*Figure*") > 0 Then
                cel.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignLeft
            End If
        Next cel

     End With
Next WS
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your code is that you were setting SrchRng only outside the worksheets loop and without any explicit worksheets qualification, so that it was set for the currently “active” sheet at the moment of its setting and never changed inside the loop

So you may want to use this code:

```
Dim cel As Range
Dim WS As Worksheet

For Each WS In Worksheets
    For Each cel In WS.Range("$A1:$AZ200")
        If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Figure") > 0 Then cel.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignLeft
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thanks--that works perfectly. I really appreciate the explanation too.